# JavaScript か jQuery で、onchangeのタイミングで呼び出される関数へ、任意の値を引数として渡したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

**やりたいこと**

・id属性"hoge"の値がonchangeしたタイミングで、userFunc関数を呼び出す
・その際、userFunc関数へ、任意の値を引数として渡す(下記例ではa)

疑似コード

```
function userFunc(param) {
  console.log(param); //a
}
document.getElementById("hoge").onchange = userFunc("a");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userFunc.bind(null, "a")` とします。

実際は`userFunc`の第二引数として(本来は第一引数だった)イベントオブジェクトが渡りますが、無視して大丈夫です。

```js
function userFunc(param) {
  console.log(param); // "a"
}
document.getElementById("hoge").onchange = userFunc.bind(null, "a");
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id="hoge">
```

Comment: 期待通り動作したのですが、bindを使用しなければ(通常の関数のように引数を)受け取れない理由は、このタイミングで呼び出される関数は通常の関数とは異なるからですか？　イベンントのハンドラーだから？？

Comment: イベントハンドラーの関数を呼ぶのがブラウザで、登録する関数のシグニチャが「第一引数がEventのもの」と決まっているからです。

Comment: なるほど、そういう決まりがあるのですね